# android Ebook program problems in android studio

Tags: android

this is an ebook program that i got from a Android learning DVD pack.
 now its the first steps of writing the program but when i run the program in Android studio  it shows some errors.
errors are shown in this sequence :

Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'supportRtl' in package 'android'

Error:(17, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command

and here is the "android manifest" file that when i run the program its shows  alot of lines as red.

```
<font color="#000000"><span style="font-family: Consolas"><i><?</i></span></font><font color="#0000FF"><span style="font-family: Consolas"><b>xml version=</b></span></font><font color="#008000"><span style="font-family: Consolas"><b>"1.0" </b></span></font><font color="#0000FF"><span style="font-family: Consolas"><b>encoding=</b></span></font><font color="#008000"><span style="font-family: Consolas"><b>"utf-8"</b></span></font><font color="#000000"><span style="font-family: Consolas"><i>?></i></span></font>
<<font color="#000080"><b>manifest </b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>xmlns:android=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>package=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"com.example.ebook_1.ebook_1"
</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>android:versionCode=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"1"
</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>android:versionName=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"1.0" </b></font>>

    <<font color="#000080"><b>uses-sdk
</b></font><font color="#660e7a"><b>android</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>:minSdkVersion=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"15"
</b></font><font color="#660e7a"><b>android</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>:targetSdkVersion=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"23" </b></font>/>

    <<font color="#000080"><b>application
</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>android:allowBackup=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"true"
</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>android:icon=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"@drawable/ebook_launcher"
</b></font><font color="#660e7a"><b>android</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>:label=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"@string/app_name"
</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>android:supportRtl=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"true"
</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>android:supportsRtl=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"true"
</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>android:theme=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"@style/AppTheme" </b></font>>
        <<font color="#000080"><b>activity
</b></font><font color="#660e7a"><b>android</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>:name=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"com.example.ebook_1.ebook_1.main_page"
</b></font><font color="#660e7a"><b>android</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>:label=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"@string/app_name"
</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>android:theme=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" </b></font>>
            <<font color="#000080"><b>intent-filter</b></font>>
                <<font color="#000080"><b>action </b></font><font color="#660e7a"><b>android</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>:name=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"android.intent.action.MAIN" </b></font>/>

                <<font color="#000080"><b>category </b></font><font color="#660e7a"><b>android</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>:name=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" </b></font>/>
            </<font color="#000080"><b>intent-filter</b></font>>
        </<font color="#000080"><b>activity</b></font>>
        <<font color="#000080"><b>activity
</b></font><font color="#660e7a"><b>android</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>:name=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"com.example.ebook_1.ebook_1.tblOfContent"
</b></font><font color="#660e7a"><b>android</b></font><font color="#0000ff"><b>:label=</b></font><font color="#008000"><b>"@string/title_activity_tbl_of_content" </b></font>/>
    </<font color="#000080"><b>application</b></font>>

<font color="#000000"><span style="font-family: Consolas"></</span></font><font color="#000080"><span style="font-family: Consolas"><b>manifest</b></span></font><font color="#000000"><span style="font-family: Consolas">></span></font>
```

and also "R"  file sign is red everywhere but i cant find "R" file anywhere.

and this is java main code if needed :

```
    package com.example.ebook_1.ebook_1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main_page extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        TextView logo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLogo);

        logo.setTypeface(
                    Typeface.createFromAsset(
                            getAssets(),getString(R.string.my_nastaliq_font));

        );



    }


    public void onBtnTblContentClick(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,tblOfContent.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onBtnFavoriteClick(View v)
    {

    }

    public void onBtnSearchClick(View v)
    {

    }

    public void onBtnSettingsClick(View v)
    {

    }

    public void onBtnAboutmeClick(View v)
    {
        alert_me(getString(R.string.about_me_title),
                getString(R.string.about_me_message),true);
    }

    public void onBtnWebsiteClick(View v)
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.irprogram.com");
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onBtnContactmeClick(View v)
    {
        alert_me(getString(R.string.contact_me_title),
                getString(R.string.contact_me_message),true);
    }

    public void onBtnExitClick(View v)
    {
        finish();
    }

    public void alert_me(String title,String message,boolean cacelable)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert =new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setCancelable(cacelable);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setMessage(message);
        alert.create();
        alert.show();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you "Open Project" or "Import Project" ? If the project was built using Eclipse, you have to "Import Project".

Comment: i write this program little by little from the begining. and not import it.

Answer (score 0):

Android Manifest files are xml files which are under the manifests folder in the Android view of the project. xml posted by you is not the actual Manifest file.

Secondly, could you add the minimum api level that your project is set to. Sometimes the minimum API level will be too low in an out of box learning tools. You can find the api level set in the build.gradle file.

Try settings the Min API level to 21 or above.

Comment: i use youwave for android and its api set to 15 and i cant change api level to 21.and i cant use genymotion because my computer is to old and cant handle that program.